# Min and Max for $a\in R^n$

Tags: real-analysis

Let $a, x\in R^n$ with $a \ne 0$.

Show that

a.) $1/\|a^2\| =  \min\{\|x\|^2 :\langle a,x\rangle = 1\}$

b. ) $\|a\| = \max\{\langle a,x\rangle : \|x\|= 1\}$

I don't have any idea on how to start on this problem.

As $\langle a,x\rangle = 1$ means either $a$ and $x$ are pointing in the same direction and are unit. Or if they are both pointing in same direction, and if are not unit vectors then the length of one vector is reciprocal of other.

For $||x|| = 1$ and $<a,x> = ||a||. ||x_/||$, where $x_/$ is the component of $x$ parallel to $a$ . Not sure how to proceed for part b either.

What would be the solution?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$\langle a,x\rangle=1$ geometrically means that $\|a\|\cdot\|x_\parallel\|=1$ where $x=x_\perp+x_\parallel$ with $x_\parallel\parallel a$ and $x_\perp\perp a$, and $x_\parallel$ points in the same direction as $a$ (and not the opposite).
The set of such points $x$ is the *hyperplane* orthogonal to $a$  which contains $b:=\dfrac a{\|a\|^2}$.

Prove that the minimum of exercise a) is taken at $x=b$, and the maximum of exercise b) is taken at $x=\dfrac a{\|a\|}$.

Comment: Can you please give a bit more intuition on how did you arrive at $b$?

Comment: Consider the line $\lambda a$ and calculate $\lambda$ to obtain a vector satisfying $\langle a,\lambda a\rangle=1$.